# Python Looping through a group of lists

Tags: python, loops

Is is possible to loop through a selection of list names?

So for example:

```
list_A=[12,3,6]
list_B=[3,42,6]
list_C=[44,33]


for i in list_A:
     i=i*4
```

but instead of doing this many times, I wanted to do a list on top of this:

```
to_loop = [list_A,list_B,list_C]

for l in to_loop:
     for i in list_A:
           i=i*4
```

Comment: You can indeed loop through a list of lists. Do you mean you want to loop through their elements as well?

Comment: depends what you want, but this question has been asked many many times, did you search first before posting?

Comment: yep, I will be looping through elements with in the lists.

Comment: What do you want `i` to be in that loop's first iteration? `1`, or  `[1]`, or `'list_A'`?

Comment: I just want to avoid writing the loop many times, so was hoping I could do it all in  a nested loop

Comment: I think your next question will be about actually replacing the values in the list, which you are NOT doing here. for l in to_loop: list_x = [i*4 for i in list_x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully sure what you are asking here but if you are wanting to loop through the items in each list as a whole it is rather simple just loop twice.

```
    list_A=[1]
    list_B=[3,42,6]
    list_C=[44,33]

    to_loop = [list_A,list_B,list_C]

    for l in to_loop:
          for i in l:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary!

```
to_loop = {"list_A":[1], "list_B":[3,42,6], "list_C":[44,33]}

for l in to_loop:
      print(l)          #Will print the name of the list
      print(to_loop[l]) #Will print the list itself
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt (you probably tested it). However you can make it a two dimensional array (untested):

```
arrayNumbers= [ [1], [3, 42, 6], [44, 33] ]

for l in arrayNumbers:
      do something(l)
```

Than first something will be called with [1], than with [3, 42, 6], than with [44, 33]
Inside something you can further looping over these sub lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_A=[1]
list_B=[3,42,6]
list_C=[44,33]

to_loop = [list_A,list_B,list_C]

for l in to_loop:
    for x in l:
        print x
```

- The above code will print every element in every list
- to_loop = [list_A, list_B, list_C] indicates a list of lists and not a list of list names.

**Output:**

```
1
3
42
6
44
33
```